# Rank over partition from postgresql in elasticsearch

Tags: sql, postgresql, elasticsearch, window-functions

We are facing a problem with migration a large data set into elasticsearch from postgres (backup or whatever).

We have schema similar like this

```
+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|    user_id    |  created_at  |  latitude  | longitude |
+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|       5       |  23.1.2015   |    12.49   |    20.39  |
+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|       2       |  23.1.2015   |    12.42   |    20.32  |
+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|       2       |  24.1.2015   |    12.41   |    20.31  |
+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|       5       |  25.1.2015   |    12.45   |    20.32  |
+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|       1       |  23.1.2015   |    12.43   |    20.34  |
+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|       1       |  24.1.2015   |    12.42   |    20.31  |
+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
```

And we are able to find a latest position by created_at thanks to rank function in SQL

```
... WITH locations AS ( 
select user_id, lat, lon, rank() over (partition by user_id order by created_at) as r
FROM locations)
SELECT user_id, lat, lon FROM locations WHERE r = 1
```

and the result is only newest created locations for each user:

```
+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|    user_id    |  created_at  |  latitude  | longitude |
+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|       2       |  24.1.2015   |    12.41   |    20.31  |
+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|       5       |  25.1.2015   |    12.45   |    20.32  |
+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|       1       |  24.1.2015   |    12.42   |    20.31  |
+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
```

After we import the data into elasticsearch, our document model looks like:

```
{
   "location" : { "lat" : 12.45, "lon" : 46.84 },
   "user_id"  : 5,
   "created_at" : "2015-01-24T07:55:20.606+00:00"
}
etc...
```

I am looking for alternatives for this SQL query in elasticsearch query, I think it must be possible, but i did not find how yet.

Comment: What is `contracts` ?

Comment: @wildplasser sorry, i wrote wrong table name, now it is fixed

Comment: If {user_id, reated_at} is unique in your table, your problem reduces to finding the records with the oldest created_at per user_id.

Comment: yes, but in relation databases if you make something like select max(created_at), user_id from locations group_by user_id, fields *lat* and *lon* must be present in group clause, and there is no warranty the *lat* and *lon* fields belongs to column with newest / oldest created_at record... i need the lat lon values... thats why iam using rank over

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using `field collapsing` clubbed with `inner_hits`.

```
{
    "collapse": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "inner_hits": {
            "name": "order by created_at",
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
                {
                    "created_at": "desc"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
}
```

Detailed Article: https://blog.francium.tech/sql-window-function-partition-by-in-elasticsearch-c2e3941495b6

Answer (score 0):

It is simple: if you want to find the *oldest* record (for a given id), you just need the records for which *no older ones* (with the same id) exist. (this assumes that for a given id, no records exist with the *same* created_at date)

---

```
SELECT * FROM locations ll
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM locations nx
   WHERE nx.user_id = ll.user_id
   AND nx.created_at > ll.created_at
   );
```

---

EDITED (it appears the OP wants the *newst* observation, not the oldest)

Comment: Actual it does not matter if i want oldest / newest (i can always change partion over order by created_at DESC/ASC), the main question is how to transform this query to elasticsearch query....

Comment: I dont know anything about elastic search (sorry), I just added a version that avoids the window function. (there a a few more possibilities)

Comment: No, it is a correct answer to your question. You asked for a reformulation of the query, and I gave you one.

Comment: It is not, Ive asked for a reformulation of the SQL query into Elasticsearch query ... its written in Heading, it is added in tags.. and ive wrote it **I am looking for alternatives for this SQL query in elasticsearch query, i think it must be possible, but i did not find how yet...** and elasticsearch is not a relation database system...

Answer (score 0):

use top_hits.

```
    "aggs": {
    "user_id": {
    "terms": {"field": "user_id"},
    "aggs": {
        "top_location": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": { "created_at": "asc" },
            "_source": []
          }
        }
    }
 }
}
```